# Suggestions for Performing Joins Between Disparate Databases

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two databases, one with entity tables and one with reporting tables that reference the entity data. Originally these tables coexisted in the same database instance and reporting queries could join with the entity tables directly. For architectural reasons,  reporting was split into a separate MySQL instance and it is no longer possible to join with the entity tables directly. For most cases, this isn't a problem because the reports can be generated with one query against the reporting data and then a second query against the entity database to fill in the missing entity data.

In some cases, though, when a report query needs to be filtered by data from the entity tables, it makes it necessary to first query the entity table and then pass a list of entity ids as a part of the reporting query. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO_REPORTS WHERE DATE BETWEEN X AND Y AND FOO_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6...)
```

This is awkward, but works most of the time. The problem we've run into is that in some cases the where clause can cause the query to exceed the MySQL max packet length. Rather than increasing the max packet length arbitrarily, I wonder if there are some other ways to solve this.

I have considered creating a temporary table and populating it with the filter list and performing a join against it. The inserts can be split into multiple statements to avoid hitting the max packet length.

I have also considered filtering the results from the report programmatically, but doing so will break report paging.

Any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you set up master-master replication between the MySQL instances then you can run the query for both databases on the same box. This would assume you have network connectivity between the MySQL servers to allow replication.